# Oracle SQL concat strings

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to concat 3 strings. Title, first name and last name. Either of them may be null.

I did this:

```
title || '.' || ' ' || fname || ' ' || lname
```

However, if `title` is null for example, I don't want the '.' and the space in front of `fname`.

Comment: Maybe you need to use [CASE](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search%3Ftag%3Dhow-to-use-case-in-select-statement) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```sql
WITH t
     AS (SELECT '' AS title, 'fname1' AS fname, 'lname1' AS lname FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Mr' AS title, 'fname2' AS fname, '' AS lname FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Ms' AS title, '' AS fname, 'lname3' AS lname FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Mr' AS title, '' AS fname, '' AS lname FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '' AS title, '' AS fname, 'lname5' AS lname FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '' AS title, 'fname6' AS fname, '' AS lname FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '' AS title, '' AS fname, '' AS lname FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Mrs' AS title, 'fname8' AS fname, 'lname8' AS lname
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT TRIM (
             (CASE
                 WHEN NVL (t.title, '#na') != '#na'
                 THEN
                    t.title || '.' || ' '
                 ELSE
                    ''
              END)
          || (CASE
                 WHEN NVL (t.fname, '#na') != '#na' THEN t.fname || ' '
                 ELSE ''
              END)
          || (CASE
                 WHEN NVL (t.lname, '#na') != '#na' THEN t.lname
                 ELSE ''
              END))
          AS fullName
  FROM t;
```

---

result:

| fullName |
| --- |
| fname1 lname1 |
| Mr. fname2 |
| Ms. lname3 |
| Mr. |
| lname5 |
| fname6 |
| [empty] |
| Mrs. fname8 lname8 |

Answer (score 2):

Use a case expression to test for title is null and concatenate accordingly, e.g:

```
case
     when title IS NULL then fname || ' ' || lname 
     else title || '.' || ' ' || fname || ' ' || lname
end as my_concatenation
```